# Following a CodeIgniter Tutorial and recieving a Fatal Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am following a video tutorial for CodeIgniter, my code is exactly like the tutorial, but I am getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object /public_html/application/models/site_model.php on line 7`

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with the code I have below?

This is line 7

```
$q = $this->db->get('test');
```

This is the full code of the page

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model {

  function getALL () {
    $q = $this->db->get('test');

    if($q->num_row() > 0) {
      foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
      return $data; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$this->db` [object] is not initialized, neither in `class Site_model` nor `CI_Model` ... know what I mean?

Comment: you have probably different CI installation

Comment: Though your answer was not the answer for this exact issue, your answer is partially correct because you now have to add CI_ in front of the model and controller classes, when the older tutorials don't show that. I want to note this incase someone runs into this issue, because two days ago that was my first issue I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to autoload.php in application/config/autoload.php and add this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); // add database in array
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgnitor you have use "$q->num_row()" to make that to "$q->num_rows()"

Change like below line

```
if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use the database object, you have to load it, by adding:

```
$this->load->database();
```

So after the changes it resembles this:

```
function getALL () {
    $this->load->database();
    $q = $this->db->get('test');
```

PS: I would recommend autoloading libs you will need throughout every page (a database object is usually one of them) or at least loading in the constructor.